# Save QGIS canvas as image with world file by python code

Tags: qgis, raster, world-file

I have to make georeferenced TIF files from some WMS layers.
Using built-in Project SaveAsImage makes file, that is too complicated for my fieldwork program Topos. My program can't read rasters with 4 channels and 32 bit, like QGIS makes.
I want to use something like

```
img=QImage(QSize(800,600), QImage.Format_RGB16)
```

Or any other solution to change raster options.
Or any solution to make some plugin for this work.

Answer (score 2):

The `Save As Image` does let you save in other image formats. For example, here's a PNG I just made that way, and its a normal 8 bit colour RGBA image:

```
preston.png: PNG image data, 981 x 734, 8-bit/color RGBA, non-interlaced
```

and it comes with its own world file, of course:

```
$ cat preston.pgw 
11.35138435140873803
0 
0 
-11.35138435140873803
348178.41769636055687442
433834.36515984922880307
```

Comment: Anyway my task is to make tif with world file from python console, user script or plugin. Its daily work to prepare fieldwork data and no sense to convert png or any other type later with graphics program. I'm looking for some suitable command.

Comment: Please edit your question to make it clear you need a TIFF, since the PNG created is a perfectly good "georeferenced raster file" as per your question. Ideally, also supply us with example TIFF files that are and aren't acceptable to your (unnamed) fieldwork program so we can tell if we're near the mark.